# Customized pagination in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am working to develop [this type of pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVPa7.jpg) for posts on a homepage, search page, archives and on an author's page. I am requesting the server to display the submitted value (current page number), and if the page form value is empty, use 1. I am taking values and displaying them on the same page.

I can't figure out why it is not working, however.
Here is my code snippet:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged))
        $paged = 1;
    else
    {
        $paged = $_GET['paged'];
    }
    if(isset($paged) && is_numeric($paged) && ($paged <= $pages) && ($paged >= 1))    //validation
    {
        if($pages == '')
        {
            global $wp_query;
            $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
            if(!$pages)
                $pages = 1;
        }

        if(1 != $pages)
        {
            ?>

            <form action="#" method="get" >Page
                <input type="text" name="paged" value="<?php echo $paged; ?>">
                of <?php echo $pages; ?>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>

            <?php
            if($paged > 1)
                echo "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($paged - 1) . "'>&lsaquo; Prev Page</a>";
            if($paged < $pages)
                echo "<a href=\"" . get_pagenum_link($paged + 1) . "\">Next Page &rsaquo;</a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Im not even sure what are trying to do? it looks like farrago of random blocks of code. What are trying to paginate?

Comment: "not working" is as useful as a chocolate teapot! Please explain what IS happening and precisely what is not happening that should be.

Comment: @DavidChase I have posts that displays on homepage, search page, archives and on author's page. I want to accomplish this type of pagination http://i.imgur.com/eSlHsIH.jpg Here in this code I have requested the server to display the submitted value (i.e. current page number) and if page form value is empty take it as 1. All this operation takes place on same place.